# Is it possible to change a button's text in TinyMCE at runtime?

Tags: tinymce

I have a custom button that I'd like to toggle the text on when it's clicked. Is there a way to get a reference to the button in it's `onAction` delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinyMCE does not support the changing of the button's text once its been rendered to the toolbar.  The only state you can really change after the toolbar appears is the disabled/enabled state.

Comment: OK, that's what I was afraid of. I'm surprised a reference to the button isn't passed in as part of the buttonAPI. Oh well, thanks.

Comment: Part of the issue is that if the text length changes you can get some crazy outcomes trying to adapt the toolbar at runtime.  The edge cases are the "fun" so we have never supported this particular use case.